# Adding a taxonomy term to acf_form()

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the acf_form() function from Advanced Custom Fields to allow users to create posts through a front end form on my WordPress site.

What I can’t get my head around is how to add a taxonomy term from a custom taxonomy to those posts when they are created.

Here is the code I have so far which is working well to create the post.

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => $submission_id,
    'post_title'    => true,
    'post_content'  => false,
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => '2017-submission',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    ),
    'submit_value' => __("Save", 'acf'),
));
```

And here something similar to what I would expect to work. Lines 8 and 9 are made up.

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => $submission_id,
    'post_title'    => true,
    'post_content'  => false,
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => '2017-submission',
        'post_status'   => 'publish', 
        'key' => 'project-category', // This is made up and does not work
        'value' => 'housing', // This is made up and does not work
    ),
    'submit_value' => __("Save", 'acf'),
));
```